# SparkSQL and UDT

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to use SparkSQL (v.1.3.0) to access a PostgreSQL database. In this database I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 id bigint,
 values double precision[]
);
```

For accessing the table, I use

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestRead").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://...",
  "dbtable" -> "schema.test",
  "user" -> "...",
  "password" -> "..."))

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM schema.test")
```

However, every time I try to access the table containing this array I get a `java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported type 2003`.

I have found an example within the Spark test code that creates a UDT in Spark for a two-dimensional point (see [ExamplePointUDT.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/test/ExamplePointUDT.scala#L31)). However, I do not understand how I could possibly use this code.

Comment: When looking into SparkSQL UDT today, I found that it is not yet a stable public API, per [mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg23986.html) and [source annotation/comments](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/SQLUserDefinedType.java).

Comment: I get this error even when accessing a hive2 server through jbdc with spark, like this hive.load("jdbc", Map(
      "url" -> "jdbc:hive2://ip:port/;auth=noSasl",
      "driver" -> "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
      "dbtable" -> "default.weeks",
      "user" -> "user",
      "password" -> ""
    ))

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, at least in **pyspark** by casting inside the query.
Don't let unsupported types reach spark, cast them at your db, and then cast them back after getting the table.

I'm not sure the syntax is correct, but it would go something like this:

```
val query_table = "(SELECT id, CAST(values AS TEXT) FROM schema.test) AS casted_table"

val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://...",
  "dbtable" -> query_table,
  "user" -> "...",
  "password" -> "..."))

jdbcDF.map(x => (x.id, x.values.toArray))
```

I'm pretty sure there is no `.toArray` that will cast a string representation back to an array, it's just place holder code.. But now it's just a matter of parsing it correctly.

Of course, this is just a patch, but it works.